# pass in object and convert it on the fly

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have access to an abstract method that takes a type called 'Weapon'.

The object I pass in has a reference to the parent, but I have to do a conversion.

Doing it one time seems to work ok, but for other methods, I might need to pass it 3, 4, or even 5 objects, which means I'd end up having to convert all of those before I could access the properties I needed.

Is there a way to pass in the conversion instead of the actual object that contains the reference?

Something like this, and I know this doesn't compile:

```
GetRobotSystems(Weapon r=(MilitaryRobot)r.Baserobot)
```

Here is the working code:

```
protected override IEnumerable<WeaponsCollection> GetRobotSystems(Weapon robot)
{
    MilitaryRobot r = (MilitaryRobot)robot.BaseRobot;

    yield return r.Aromor;
    yield return r.Weapons;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  If the method expects a `MilitaryRobot`, why not change the method declaration accordingly?

Comment: I get the feeling the root cause of the issue is with your design and to give you any specific help you will need to post at least part of your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface approach that Eric describes is an excellent solution to this kind of game object problem, but composition can work too.

The problem is it looks like you're mixing composition and inheritance patterns here which will end up with a bit a mess.

The idea of having a higher level "game object" with Weapon/Armour properties is fine. This is a composition pattern.

But why then have a Robot/MilitaryRobot inheritance pattern? You could factor out the features that distinguish the difference between these different types and change them to properties on a more generic "Actor" or "GameObject".

Composition patterns like this work great in game design. But inheritance patterns will probably lead to brittle and almost impossible to refactor code.

Answer (score 4):

> I have access to an abstract method that takes a type called 'Weapon'.

No, you don't have an abstract method.  It only knows how to handle objects of type MilitaryRobot.

If all Weapon.BaseRobot have properties Armor and Weapons, then there is no need to cast to MilitaryRobot.  If not all Weapon.BaseRobot have those properties, you may as well change the method signature to accept the one concrete type that the method knows how to handle.

Note that when writing this type of code, interfaces are extremely helpful.  For example, you could define IWeaponized and have anything that has weapons implement that interface, while anything that is armored could implement an interface IArmored.  Something that is both weaponized and armored would implement both of those interfaces.  Your generic methods would accept interfaces, not classes.